# Laravel - Optional where and whereJsonConatins not working correctly

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

PHP 7.2.10

Laravel 5.6.39

```
  $statuses = [4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13];
    $notStatuses = [14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19];

    $videos = Video::query();

    if ( isset( $queryParams['category'] ) ){
        $videos = $videos->where('video_category', '=', $queryParams['category']);
    }
    if ( isset( $queryParams['language'] ) ){
        $videos = $videos->where('video_language', '=', $queryParams['language']);  
    }

    $videos = $videos->where(function($query) use($statuses) {
        foreach($statuses as $status) {
            $query->orWhereJsonContains('video_status_ids', $status);
        }
    });

    $videos = $videos->where(function($query) use($notStatuses) {
        foreach($notStatuses as $status) {
            $query->whereJsonDoesntContain('video_status_ids', $status);
        }
    });


    $videos = $videos->orderBy('video_priority', 'desc')->latest()->paginate(10);

    return $videos;
```

language and category are optional filters in current condition let's consider language filter, if there is no video with the selected language, even then I will get videos with status 10 and 11,

if I will use `whereJsonContains` above the filters then also it is giving wrong result, how I should use whereJsonContains, whereJsonDoesNotContains and optional wheres correctly?

*Note: may be helpful to get the issue correctly*

You can also reverse the situation

```
 $statuses = [4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13];
 $notStatuses = [14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19];
```

below image showing manual tagger hindi videos, but it can be seen the choosen filters are auto tagger and Indonesian.

[image]

Query generated for

```
http://mysite.dev/admin/tagging-in-progress?_token=d4jQOLDixYSEXhMR2z8OihVPQ2ZKTezJhk3tIWJg&category=manual_tagger&language=maltese&video_status=&submit=
```

is

```
select * from `videos` where `video_category` = 'manual_tagger' and `video_language` = 'english' and json_contains(`video_status_ids`, 9) or json_contains(`video_status_ids`, 29)  order by `video_priority` desc, `created_at` desc limit 10 offset 0
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185907/discussion-on-question-by-prafulla-kumar-sahu-laravel-optional-where-and-where).

Comment: @JonasStaudenmeir please have a look at updates on question and also the chat, may be only you can help me.

Answer (score 1):

try after change :

```
WhereJsonContains('video_status_ids', $status)
```

to

```
whereRaw('JSON_CONTAINS(video_status_ids, "$status")')
```

But, Best way is normalize DB structure.

Example:

post like table :

```
+---------+---------+
| user_id | post_id |
+---------+---------+
|       1 |     1,2 |
|       2 |     1,5 |
+---------+---------+
```

normalize tabel

```
+---------+---------+
| user_id | post_id |
+---------+---------+
|       1 |       1 |
|       1 |       2 |
|       2 |       1 |
|       2 |       5 |
+---------+---------+
```

I don't know is it usable in your condition or not. but if is it then normalize table

Comment: I tried this but sadly, it is not giving a single record by the about normalization, there are some situation we are given and can not create or change it, just bound to work on it, you can understand it, right.

Answer (score 0):

just try this one

```
$video = $videos->where(function($query) use($statuses) {
        foreach($statuses as $status) {
            $query->orWhereJsonContains('video_status_ids', $status);
        }
    })->where(function($query) use($notStatuses) {
        foreach($notStatuses as $status) {
            $query->whereJsonDoesntContain('video_status_ids', $status);
        }
    })
->orderBy('video_priority', 'desc')->latest()->paginate(10);
```

Comment: Please see the question, it also has optional filters.

Comment: @Prafulla Kumar Sahu , yes i saw the optional filter i  just written the all ``where `` conditions in single query ..

Comment: Dear friend, I know that, but the question is different, the question is how to use optional where with whereJsonConatins and whereJsonDoesNotContains clause.